# How can I build a list recursively? ML

Tags: list, recursion, ml

I have to write a recursive function that takes a list of three elements, and returns another list created using those three elements.  For example I might have a list like [a,b,c], and a function needs to multiple a by b c times. So [2,3,5] would create a list like [2,6,18,54,162,486]

I understand the hd, tl, @, and :: list operators, but I don't understand the logic of building the list.

If I multiply hd([2,3,5])* hd(tl([2,3,5)) I'll get six. But where do I attach that?  I would need new logic on every call to go deeper in the list multiplying the last element by 3.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Example net using function multiply]

The point is, your recursive function should return the list, and the call which satisfies the stopping requirement should return empty list (or some starting list).

In this case, the function appends (a * b) to the start of list of the next values. The decreasing c provides a counter, while intermediate result (a * b) serves as a base for calculations further down the line. So here the list grows backwards, from the greatest values at the tail to the smallest at the head.